# C++: std::unique_ptr& doesn't recognize inheritance?

Tags: c++

Maybe there is a flaw in my understanding of this. It is my understanding that a `unique_ptr<A>` will allow you to initialize it using a `B`, as long as `B` is derived from `A`.
I cannot seem to get this to work when returning a `unique_ptr<B>` from a function that returns `unique_ptr<A>&`, however.
Here is a really dumbed-down example of the code I'm using:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    A(int a) : a (a) {}
};
struct B : public A
{
    B(int b) : A (b+1) {}
};

struct Hi
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a_ptr;
    std::unique_ptr<B> b_ptr;

    Hi()
    {
        a_ptr = std::unique_ptr<A> (new A(7));
        b_ptr = std::unique_ptr<B> (new B(16));
    }

    std::unique_ptr<A>& GetPtr(int foo)
    {
        if(foo < 10)
            return a_ptr;
        else
            return b_ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Hi hi;
    return hi.GetPtr(11)->a;
}
```

Returning `b_ptr` as a `std::unique_ptr<A>&` yields this error even though `B` is a public child of `A`:

```
src/core/memory/../rom/Rom.h:74:18: error: non-const lvalue reference to type
  'unique_ptr<A>' cannot bind to a value of
  unrelated type 'unique_ptr<B>'
    return b_ptr;
           ^~~~~
```

Comment: Why does `Hi::GetPtr` return a reference to a smart pointer, instead of a smart pointer?

Comment: Because, by my understanding, if it returns a unique_ptr it will need to create another unique_ptr from that one, which is illegal (not unique)

Comment: If your class wants to own the `A` and `B` objects then it should either (1) return a reference to the `A` and `B` objects (not the smart pointer) `A& GetPtr(int foo) { return foo < 10 ? *a : *b; }` or (2) forgo smart pointers, and have `Hi` directly have private `A` and `B` objects.